# Why are there conflicting solutions to this problem concerning circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

Original problem:

> A particle is moving along a circumference of radius $R$ according to the law  $l = a\sin(\omega t)$ where $l$ is the displacement from the original position along the circumference, $a$ and $w$ are constants. Given that $R=1.00m, a=0.80m, \omega= 2.00rads^{-1}$ compute:
>
> 1. The overall (total) acceleration of the particle at points $l=0$ and $\pm a$.
> 2. The min value of the total acceleration $a_{min}$ and the corresponding displacement $l_{min}$.

I've approached the 1st part of Q1 like so:

As $l = a\sin(\omega t) \rightarrow a_t=-(a\omega^2)\sin(\omega t)$ and as $l = 0 \rightarrow \sin(\omega t) = 0$. Hence $a_t = 0$. The book agrees with me on that.

Now $a_n = R\omega^2$, hence $a_n = 1*2^2= 4ms^{-2}= a_{total}$. The book seems to ignore the fact that it gave the angular frequency and uses $a_n = v^2/R$ where $v=l'$ to arrive at a completely different result where $a_{total}=(a^2\omega^2)/R= 2.6 ms^{-2}$. Is this simply a mistake, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: It is unclear to me whether this is linear simple harmonic motion (your equation seems to indicate this is one dimensional), or circular motion (as stated in the title of the question). This may be a result of translation. But unless you clear up that confusion, you will continue to get conflicting "solutions".

Comment: @Floris this is circular motion

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the confusion here is due to the two frequencies in the problem. In the equation you give for radial acceleration, $a=R\omega^2$, the frequency $\omega$ relates to the time it takes to make a full loop around the circle. In the problem statement, $\omega$ refers to the time it takes to complete an oscillation. Since these frequencies aren't the same, you get a different answer. The one in the book is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

$\omega$ is $\textit{not}$ angular velocity of point about circle's center. Therefore $a_n\neq R\omega^2$, in fact the quantity on the right side does not mean anything. Book's solution is correct, because if point has tangential speed $v$ at a given time then its angular velocity about the circle's center is $v/R$.

Answer (score 1):

Your particle is moving in a circle, but it is NOT (quite) executing simple harmonic motion. Instead, it is accelerating and decelerating as it is going around (parts of) the circle.

Therefore, to do this calculation you need to compute the actual velocity vector (and its derivative) at given points.

When you are at the extremes of the motion, the particle has zero velocity, but it is "reversing direction" and therefore has a certain acceleration given by

$$\ddot x = -a \omega^2$$

On this point you and the book agree.

But when the particle is in the middle of its path, its acceleration is purely tangential, and therefore the acceleration is purely radial. The velocity at this point is given by

$$v = a\omega$$

and the acceleration is $\frac{v^2}{R} = \frac{a^2\omega^2}{R}$.

You are asusming that the angular velocity (of the motion in the circle) is $\omega$ - but it isn't. The angular velocity is $\frac{v}{R}$.

The following diagram (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oscillating_pendulum.gif) might give you more insight into what is going on. It roughly describes the motion from your problem (for small angles, it is a very good approximation):

[image]

The angular displacement $\theta$ is a function of time: $\theta = \frac{a}{R} \sin\omega t$. And the angular velocity $\dot\theta$ is the time derivative of this: $\dot\theta = \omega \frac{a}{R}\cos\omega t$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I didn't get what you meant when you said "its acceleration is purely tangential, and therefore the acceleration is purely radial." Also, if $w$ is not the angular velocity/frequency (are the two the same?), then what is it? Its definitely measured in rads^-1

Comment: Note that "angular velocity" and "frequency" are sometimes the same thing; at other times they are not. There is a _time_ (or _phase_) angle of the motion, $\omega t$, and there is a _physical_ angle of displacement, $\theta$. Their relationship should be clear from my updated answer. They are not the same thing - and depending on what you are looking at, you need to use the right one...